# Load different content onclick of different controls

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to load different content `onclick` of different button controls. Since I am new to JavaScript and don't know where I am doing wrong.

It will be highly appreciated if there is any help from any one of you!

The code of which is here:

```
 (function () {

        var getText = document.getElementById('text'),
            getSmallImage = document.getElementById('smallimage'),
            getLargeImage = document.getElementById('largeimage');

        function ChangeState(event) {

            var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
            myDiv.className = 'dynamicDiv';
            document.body.appendChild(myDiv);

            //style the div
            var a = document.getElementsByClassName('dynamicDiv')
            for (var i in a) {

                a[i].style.width = '400px';
                a[i].style.height = '400px';
                a[i].style.color = 'rgb(255,255,0)';
                a[i].style.background = 'rgb(0,102,153)';
                a[i].style.padding = '10px';
            }

            if (event.target.id == getText) {
                myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode('This is my div'));
            }

            else if (event.target.id == getSmallImage) {
                var smallImage = document.createElement('img');
                smallImage.src = 'Images/smallimage.jpg';

                myDiv.appendChild(smallImage);
            }
            else if (event.target.id == getLargeImage) {
                var largeImage = document.createElement('img');
                largeImage.src = 'Images/largeimage.jpg';

                myDiv.appendChild(largeImage);
            }
        }

        getText.addEventListener('click', ChangeState, false);
        getSmallImage.addEventListener('click', ChangeState, false);
        largeimage.addEventListener('click', ChangeState, false);
    }
   ());
```

and the HTML code is here:

```
<input id="text" type="button" value="Click to load Text" />
<input id="smallimage" type="button" value="Click to load Small Image" / />
<input id="largeimage" type="button" value="Click to load Large Image" />
```

and same code is on jsfiddler as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/shabirgilkar/c7fBk/

Comment: What is this: `else (event.target.id == getLargeImage) {...`? A typo in the post, or a missing `if` in your code?

Comment: @Teemu Actually I checked on w3schools website how to write if else conditional statement. It is mentioned like this way. Can you please look into jsfiddle version and see how I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: You fiddle is somehow not finished, there's only a half of the code... I doubt even w3schools would write if-else like that.

Comment: @teemu here is the w3schools link http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: @Teemu and here is the online version of this where you could get the course  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27803278/LoadDynamicResources/index.html

Comment: Now  if you read carefully the article, there's no mention about `else (condition) {}`.

Comment: Usually it's not a good idea to edit the post according to answers/comments. You clearly had that error in your code. Now you've cleaned up your post, and future visitors can't understand some comments/answers just because they can't find the error from the post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem had been fixed by my friends help and many thanks to @teemu for what ever you did. The resolved code is given below:

```
   (function () {

        function ChangeState(event) {

            var myDiv = document.createElement('div');

            //style the div
            myDiv.className = 'dynamicDiv';
            myDiv.style.color = 'rgb(255,255,0)';
            myDiv.style.background = 'rgb(0,102,153)';
            myDiv.style.padding = '10px';

            document.body.appendChild(myDiv);

            if (event.target.id == 'text') {
                myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.'));
            }

            else if (event.target.id == 'smallimage') {
                var smallImage = document.createElement('img');
                smallImage.src = 'Images/smallimage.jpg';

                myDiv.appendChild(smallImage);
            }
            else if (event.target.id == 'largeimage') {
                var largeImage = document.createElement('img');
                largeImage.src = 'Images/largeimage.jpg';

                myDiv.appendChild(largeImage);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('click', ChangeState, false);
        document.getElementById('smallimage').addEventListener('click', ChangeState, false);
        document.getElementById('largeimage').addEventListener('click', ChangeState, false);

    }
   ());
```

I hope this will be helpful for some one!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
else (event.target.id == getLargeImage) {...}
```

use

```
else if (event.target.id == getLargeImage) {...}
```

Or remove the condition from the first snippet.

Also the IIFE is executed at the time when `body` and its elements don't exist, hence all the variables referring elements are `null`. Use some `load` event or place the script just before ending `body` tag.

---

**EDIT**

You've to remove `.id`s from `if (event.target.id === getText){...}`s, since your variables already refer to elements instead being their `id`s. Also it's unnecessary to create the inline-styles for all the `div`s on every click, I've removed the loop and styled the newly-created `div` only. (Though this `div` has a class name, why not use CSS to style the `div`?)

The fixed code works at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8s6U6/), notice `onLoad` selection.

Comment: If you check my Fiddler I have done the same, but still It is not working :(

Comment: I think my old fiddle link had been in-correct, now I have updated it and would appreciate if you could take relook.

Comment: @ShabirGilkar I'm sorry, this took a while. Please see my edited answer and fiddle.